# bibliographystyle{plainnat} - citations and multicitations problem

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

I'm having two main problems with my master thesis citations.
I’m using JabRef for building my bib file.

For example I have the following authors in the bib file:

1.

```
Author  = {{Silva, Peter}},
Year = {2009},
```

2.

```
Author  = {{Cash, John and Lucas, George and Noah, Steve }},
Year = {2012},
```

Problem 1:

In the master thesis, text each time I want to cite one author I would like the format to be:  last name (year). For the first case it would show: **Silva (2009)**.

At the end of the thesis when the full bibliography is listed it would show: **Silva, Peter, 2009**.

Problem 2:

In the master thesis, text each time I want to cite more than two authors I would like the format to be:  last name of first author et al. (year). For the second case it would show: **Cash et al. (2012)**.

At the end of the thesis when the full bibliography is listed it would show: **Cash, John  and  Lucas, George, and Noah, Steve, 2012.**

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The problem is due to the additional pair of braces around the author names: it should be ` Author = {Silva, Peter}` and `Author = {Cash, John and Lucas, George, and Noah, Steve}`

Comment: HI!
Thank you very much for your help and welcome greetings!

You’re right. That’s the way I used to have it, but that way when the bibliography is listed I get:

Peter Silva, 2009 and not Silva, Peter, 2009 like is showed during the citations. The citation list will not be alphabetically ordered.

Comment: Are you using the *old* system with natbib and others, or the modern `biblatex`? Can you provide a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/) so that we see your setup and can provide more specific help?

Comment: @Johannes_B - Given that the OP has stated in the title that he/she is using the `plainnat` bibliography style, I'd say it's fairly straightforward to infer that BibTeX and the `natbib` package are being used. However, this inference could be wrong...

Comment: @Mico Sorry, i wasn't given this enough attention.

Answer (score 2):

As you've confirmed in a comment, implementing @egreg's suggestion and getting rid of the extra pair of curly braces around the `author` fields (and around the `editor` fields too, while you're at it) lets LaTeX and BibTeX generate the desired citation call-out format.

To address the second issue -- listing the authors' full names as "Surname, FirstName" rather than as "FirstName Surname" -- it's necessary to modify the bibliography style file slightly. Fortunately, the required modification is straightforward.

- Start by finding the file `plainnat.bst` on your system. (If you have TeXLive or MikTeX, typing "kpsewhich plainnat.bst" at a command prompt should tell you where the file is located.) Make a copy of this file, and name the copy (say) `revplainnat.bst`.
- Open `revplainnat.bst` in a text editor, and find the function `format.names`. (It starts on line 216 in my copy of the file.)
- A few lines down from the start of the function, locate the instruction

  ```
      { s nameptr "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
  ```
- Change this string to

  ```
      { s nameptr "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, ff}" format.name$ 't :=
  ```

  You can probably guess what moving `ff` from the start to the end of the `nameptr` string does.
- Save the file `revplainnat.bst`, either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the second method, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution.
- Start using the new bibliography style by replacing `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` with `\bibliographystyle{revplainnat}` and re-running LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing!

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{newtest.bib}
@misc{pub1,
  Author = {Silva, Peter}, 
  Year   = {2009},
}
@misc{pub2,
  Author = {Cash, John and Lucas, George and Noah, Steve }, 
  Year   = {2012},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{revplainnat}

\begin{document}
\cite{pub1}

\cite{pub2}

\bibliography{newtest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Mico!
Thank you so much for you detailed and precise instructions!
I had to delete all the files compiled by LaTeX @ the main file directory and it worked like a breeze!

So many time I lost with this issue…

You’re 5*!